# Want to replace Memcache with Memcached

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, memcached

First i  installed the following as per W3 total cache instructions:

1)Installed Memcached

2)PECL Memcache Module

2 days back i went through an article comparing Memcache Vs Memcached and i installed Memcached by

3)`sudo apt-get install php5-memcached`. and

4)Did a Apache `restart`. 
Now i can see both in phpinfo.

5)I removed memcache `sudo apt-get remove php5-memcache` as i want to use Memcached

6) after uninstalling i noticed `Class 'Memcache' not found` error and wordpress in not opening.

7) then again i installed `php5-memcache`.

8) now again i can see both in phpinfo (please look at the screenshot below)
[image: php info after reinstalling php5-memcache]

Other info

9) Registered save handlers - files user memcache memcached

10) `session.save_handler`  memcache    memcache

How to repleace memcache with memcached. please advice.

Can i use both?

PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4

Web Server: Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Wordpress `Memcached` do you use ?
Because it's your only problem : you need a WP module which implements `Memcached`

For ex : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ffpc/

My advice it to uninstall php5-memcache if you use the other, to avoid confusion.

Regards